# Wpf dictionary appearance in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, listbox

I'm working on a POS system and i'm using a Dictionary to count any duplicates in my products list. 
I use following Linq for this:

```
selectedProducts.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Then i bind this Dictionary to a listbox to show it to the waiter. The problem is though, The way the Dictionary looks when binded to a listbox is unclear.

The way it appears is: [Object, Count]. Is there a way you can change the way a Dictionary appears in a Listbox?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are looking for DisplayMemberPath=Key or DisplayMemberPath=Value

Comment: @user3753988 what do you want to display? `Key`, `Value` or both?

Comment: My xaml is pretty simple, it's just the listbox. The way i bind my listbox is like this:

Dictionary counts = selectedProducts.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
lbx_Products.ItemsSource = counts;

I want to display both key and value, i just want to edit it in such way i can make it look like this: X[Key]   [Value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding an ItemTemplate to your ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=yourDictionary}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                <Label Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="{Binding Path=Key}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```